# Custom GestureRecognizer Creation

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to create custom Gesture Recognizer.

For Example: 
if user pan the screen from top to bottom some distance from there if the finger move left direction some distance, i need to invoke some method from view. same if the finger move right direction means some other function should get invoke.

For this functionality 
1. can i use UIPanGestureRecognizer and detect the user interaction throw the translation position,

2.There is any way to implement my own custom GestureRecognizer

(like: **UIPanLeftLGestureRecognizer** for user drag the finger from top to bottom some distance and moved left from there, **UIPanRightLGestureRecognizer** for user drag the finger from top to bottom some distance and moved right from there.)

Which is the best way to achieve the solution for this problem. kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked / researched creating your own gesture recognizer subclass?

Comment: no i did not tried, want to know if which is the best way to solve the problem, can u suggest me

Comment: Probably a subclass is best.

Comment: okay thank you. do u have any tutorial regarding this @Wain

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=subclassing+uigesturerecognizer+example

Answer (score 0):

I would use two `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`s with different directions like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedDown:)];
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedRight:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

And don't forget to add these gesture recognizers to appropriate view